# Gulp not generating uglified css file

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I followed a simple tutorial and followed all the commands but still uglified css file is not getting generated by gulp in the folder named "destination". Here is the code :

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

gulp.task('default', function(){
console.log("gulp is running");

return
gulp.src("source/css/style.css")
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('destination'));
});
```

My package.json files contains gulp and gulp-uglify but as dev dependencies :

```
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0"}
```

Why files are not getting generated in the destination folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
  return gulp.src("source/css/style.css", {base: "source/css/"})
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destination'));
});
```

Btw, this task only uglifies the file **when it's run**. Look at tutorials on `gulp.watch()` to create a task to wait and watch for changes and then uglify the file.

Comment: Thank you but i figured out the solution, deleting node_modules, package.json and package.json.lock and reinstalling everything via npm install gulp-uglify gulp-minify-css gulp-concat gulp solved the problem . Strange but worked.